# SMTP through HAProxy / Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, haproxy

kind of an unusual setting here:
We have an SMTP service running on Tomcat / Elastic Beanstalk on AWS in an auto-scaling group behind an ELB load-balancer.
Now, for one of our clients we need to have a static IP for the SMTP service. Since this is not possible with the out-of-the-box load-balancer on AWS, we have a separate HAProxy instance transparently routing the :25 traffic trough the AWS load-balancer.

For some reason, the HAProxy chokes after exactly 3 SMTP calls. After that connections either time out or take minutes to go through.

The interesting part is that the following configurations work perfectly fine:

- Calling the SMTP service on the AWS load-balancer directly
- Load-balancing the Elastic Beanstalk's nodes through HAProxy directly.
- Target setting with HTTP calls on port 80, instead SMTP on port 25

Help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like EC2 rate limiting what appears -- to the system -- to be "outbound" SMTP from your HAProxy instance.

You're accessing the ELB from the HAProxy by one of this outside addresses, and this is causing your traffic to be treated as Internet-bound.

> In order to maintain the quality of Amazon EC2 addresses for sending email, we enforce default limits on the amount of email that can be sent from EC2 accounts. If you wish to send larger amounts of email from EC2, you can apply to have these limits removed from your account by filling out this form.
>
> https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

One solution is to had those limits removed, but consider your next step carefully -- you'd be better served by load-balancing the EB nodes through the HAProxy directly, using the nodes' private IP addresses -- because there is a charge for traffic to your ELB from within EC2 on the public IP.

Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To ... Amazon Elastic Load Balancing ... in the same Availability Zone ... Using a public or Elastic IP address ... $0.01/GB.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Not a massive charge, perhaps, but it should be an avoidable charge nonetheless.

Additionally, there's no way to configure HAProxy to look up the IP address behind the hostname you've configured for the ELB with each request.  HAProxy resolves hostnames on startup and if the ELB's IP address changes, HAProxy will not detect this change.

On the flip side, you can't reliability configure HAProxy to directly connect to the EB instances, since they're dynamically-addressed as well.

The simplest way to prove that my diagnosis is correct is to set the ELB's TCP listener on another port, such as 587 (or 2025, or whatever), mapped to port 25 on the EB instances.  Then have the HAProxy target the traffic to port 587.  That should eliminate the EC2 rate limiting on SMTP, although you do still have an issue to deal with if the ELB's external IP changes.

Comment: Thank you! You were exactly right! I have moved the traffic between the load-balancers to a different port and now it works no problem. I might really make HAProxy directly load-balance on the nodes at some point but that will involve some scripting in order for it to listen to cluster size / IP changes on the ELB. Since there will not be a lot of traffic through that service, the proposed solution is perfectly fine for now. Thanks!